# Spring aop advice failed to wrapped proxy when the advice bean is in creation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspect

The issue is the same as [this question](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15063)
I am working with the spring aop at annotation aspect, one of my service bean cannot install annotation advice but others can.
Then I debug and found out the reason, the code in `BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper` indicates that if an `advice bean` is in creation, the `serviceBean` will failed to install the advisor.
`if (this.beanFactory.isCurrentlyInCreation(name))`

```java
public List<Advisor> findAdvisorBeans() {
    // Determine list of advisor bean names, if not cached already.
    String[] advisorNames = this.cachedAdvisorBeanNames;
    if (advisorNames == null) {
        // Do not initialize FactoryBeans here: We need to leave all regular beans
        // uninitialized to let the auto-proxy creator apply to them!
        advisorNames = BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(
                this.beanFactory, Advisor.class, true, false);
        this.cachedAdvisorBeanNames = advisorNames;
    }
    if (advisorNames.length == 0) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    List<Advisor> advisors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String name : advisorNames) {
        if (isEligibleBean(name)) {
            if (this.beanFactory.isCurrentlyInCreation(name)) {
                if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                    logger.trace("Skipping currently created advisor '" + name + "'");
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    advisors.add(this.beanFactory.getBean(name, Advisor.class));
                }
                catch (BeanCreationException ex) {
                    Throwable rootCause = ex.getMostSpecificCause();
                    if (rootCause instanceof BeanCurrentlyInCreationException) {
                        BeanCreationException bce = (BeanCreationException) rootCause;
                        String bceBeanName = bce.getBeanName();
                        if (bceBeanName != null && this.beanFactory.isCurrentlyInCreation(bceBeanName)) {
                            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                                logger.trace("Skipping advisor '" + name +
                                        "' with dependency on currently created bean: " + ex.getMessage());
                            }
                            // Ignore: indicates a reference back to the bean we're trying to advise.
                            // We want to find advisors other than the currently created bean itself.
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return advisors;
}
```

The interceptor is

```java
public class DemoInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    //do something
    return new Object();
  }

}
```

The advisor config is

`config way 1`

```java
public class DemoAdvisor implements PointcutAdvisor {

    private MethodInterceptor methodInterceptor;

    private Pointcut pointcut;

    public DemoAdvisor(MethodInterceptor methodInterceptor) {
        this.methodInterceptor = methodInterceptor;
        this.pointcut = new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(null, DemoAnno.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Advice getAdvice() {
        return this.methodInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPerInstance() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Pointcut getPointcut() {
        return this.pointcut;
    }
}



@Configuration
public class AnnoAspectConfig {

    @Bean
    public DemoAdvisor DemoAdvisor() {
        DemoAdvisor advisor = new DemoAdvisor(demoInterceptor());
        return advisor;
    }

    @Bean
    public DemoInterceptor demoInterceptor() {
        DemoInterceptor demoInterceptor = new DemoInterceptor();
        return demoInterceptor;
    }

}
```

Then I think it maybe the problem in the advice config, so I change the advice config to the below
`config way 2`

```java
@Configuration
public class ValidationAdvisor {

    @Bean
    public DefaultPointcutAdvisor demoAdvisor() {
        DemoInterceptor interceptor = new DemoInterceptor();
        AnnotationMatchingPointcut annotationMatchingPointcut = AnnotationMatchingPointcut.forMethodAnnotation(DemoAnno.class);
        DefaultPointcutAdvisor advisor = new DefaultPointcutAdvisor();
        advisor.setPointcut(annotationMatchingPointcut);
        advisor.setAdvice(interceptor);
        return advisor;
    }

}
```

**Then everything goes find, so the question is, why the `config way 1` cause the failed of advisor installation while the `config way 2` did not?**

Comment: Where is your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You are not really expecting an answer how to solve "this problem" if nobody can reproduce the problem, whatever it may be in your specific situation.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Next time please notify me of an update via comment, I just noticed by chance. The situation is getting clearer now, but where is `DemoInterceptor`? MCVE means that I can copy, compile and run your code - a little demo application would be helpful - in order to reproduce the problem. Another question is why you do AOP-related things manually instead of just using Spring AOP and use an `@Aspect` with `@Before`, `@After` or `@Around` advice.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks, I've added the interceptor. Now I think it may be the reason that the demoInterceptor in the advisor config cannot use a spring-bean, because it may cause a delay of bean creation, this is why when i change to `new DemoInterceptor()` it goes fine

Comment: Are you sure your config #2 should have class name `DemoAdvisor`? You use that class name for the advisor already. And did you notice that the bean method returning the advisor returns type `DemoAdvisor` in config #1 but `DefaultPointcutAdvisor` in config #2? This all looks a bit inconsistent. Did you actually run your code before copying & pasting it into your question or did you copy the code and edit it here without testing?

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for the help, I change the class and method name for `demoxxx` before paste.sorry for the inconsistent, in general, I think the main problem is `the xxxInterceptor in the advisor config cannot use a spring-bean` because it may cause a delay of bean creation.

Comment: Anyway, you want an answer but are unwilling to fix your own sample code even though I pointed you to inconsistencies. If you like to have an answer, I still recommend the same as in my first comment: an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks, it does have a error in `public class DemoAdvisor`, So I update it to `public class ValidationAdvisor`

Comment: You changed one word in your question. What was unclear about the term MCVE? Please follow the link and read. Thank you very much.